# How do I sort an array with letters and numbers combined in bash?

Tags: bash, sort, array

I have an array with `h4 h5 h1 h2 h3` in it and I would like to sort it according to the numbers, but don't know how. What is the best way to do this?

edit1: I would also like to sort an array via the numbers containing different letters, for example `s4 h5 q1 h2 g3`.

Comment: That's a string; do you have that, exactly, or an actual array?

Comment: i have that in an array, for example: ${array[0]} = h4,  ${array[1]} = h5,  ${array[2]} = h1,  ${array[3]} = h2,  ${array[4]} = h3

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `tr`; shell's "Parameter Expansion" with an adequate `IFS` (in a subshell) should suffice. Try

```
$ ARR=(h4 h5 h1 h2 h3)
$ SA=( $(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${ARR[*]}" | sort) )
$ BRR=(s4 h5 q1 h2 g3)
$ SB=( $(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${BRR[*]}" | sort -k1.2) )
$ echo "${SB[*]}" 
q1 h2 g3 s4 h5
```

Comment: This would be better if echo was substituted for printf

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Just print, sort and store the values in the same array name.

```
ary=(h4 h5 h1 h2 h3)
ary=(`printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}"|sort`)

echo ${ary[@]}
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an array `A` as

```
A=(h4 h5 h1 h2 h3)
```

Now, the problem with the `sort` command is that it sorts elements in different line and can't sort elements in the same line. So, the workaround is to transform the array into an element per line and sort with `sort` and put them in an array which is actually sorted, that is,

```
B=(`echo ${A[@]} | tr " " "\n" | sort`)
```

Now, B is the sorted array. Here, `tr` transforms space into a newline